# dc.js responive geojson US map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Testing with following sample code:
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/

I would like to make this map responsive to the container/window size. 
However, examples I have seen utilized topojson and SVG to scale the map. 
http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-worldmap-boilerplate.html

Is this not possible with Geojson to update the map size in a similar fashion?

```
d3.json("../geo/us-states.json", function (statesJson) {
        usChart.width(990)
                .height(500)
                .dimension(states)
                .group(stateRaisedSum)
                .colors(d3.scale.quantize().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]))
                .colorDomain([0, 200])
                .colorCalculator(function (d) { return d ? usChart.colors()(d) : '#ccc'; })
                .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) {
                    return d.properties.name;
                })
                .title(function (d) {
                    return "State: " + d.key + "\nTotal Amount Raised: " + numberFormat(d.value ? d.value : 0) + "M";
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the exact same approach as the one you linked to (techSlides).

It consists in replacing the whole `svg` by a new one **re-drawn after a resize of the window**. On redraw, the only thing that changes is the width  and height you use as dimensions of the `svg` element.

Whether your data is GeoJson ot TopoJson doesn't affect this.

A smoother variant of this technique is to resize the existing `svg` element on resize of the window, without doing a redraw. Just add an SVG `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"`, so that projection inside the SVG is kept.

Example [in this blog](https://mango-is.com/blog/business/Belgians-twitter-and-klout/), and its [javascript](https://github.com/Mango-information-systems/mango-is-blog/blob/master/blog/js/2014-09-26-Belgians-twitter-and-klout.js#L79).

Comment: Unfortunately, that changes the size of the container and the map does not redraw. Look at this example. http://bl.ocks.org/jczaplew/4444770  which also uses <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

Comment: You need to use the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes. Here's an update of your gist: https://gist.github.com/mef/566bc47c8939f69fda4f

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I saw that code before too, but it also uses topojson.v0.min.js to redraw the map. Look at this code .data(topojson.object(us, us.objects.states).geometries)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "states")
  .attr("d", path);
 });

Comment: We're turning in circles. My answer already tackled your comments. What exactly have you tried? Please share your code in a jsFiddle so we can move forward.